# How to turn off network probing in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, web-applications

Recent versions of Firefox do some background accesses to websites that are immediately aborted. (it's related to some IPv4/IPv6 decision or similar)

I am developing a web application and those probes spam my logs (each prints a multi-line stack trace)

Is there a setting in Firefox to turn this probing off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Firefox feature called *Race Cache With Network* .

Short description: Firefox sends requests for cached resources concurrently to the local disk cache and the actual network server. Whichever result arrives first is used - the other request is canceled.

The idea is that sometimes the network is faster that the cache on HDD, so this way the page is loaded faster.

To turn it off, open `about:config` and set `network.http.rcwn.enabled` to  *false*.

Sources:

- [Race Cache With Network experiment on Nightly](https://lists.mozilla.org/pipermail/dev-platform/2017-May/018543.html) (dev-platform mail list)
- [primefaces.org forum post](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=55047&start=10&sid=3f6e9efd1626b6d1d392e999466903dd)
- [Test connections in background](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=3049186) mozillaZine forum

Comment: Related bug: [RCWN causes half-open connections leading to IP blocks for SYN flooding](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1622859)